Fail to checkout svn repos (server is on Ubuntu) on windows machine
I have created a svn repository on my workstation (system: Ubuntu 22.04), and I have configured apache and ssl settings following Subversion - Community Help Wiki and SVN Server on Ubuntu with https access, thus I can successfully access svn repository via http and https on my local Ubuntu workstation.
Now I wish to checkout the repos on my laptop (system: Windows 11). My laptop and my workstation have connected to the same university network. However, when I tried to access svn repos via the same url which works on my workstation, it gave HTTP ERROR 502. I have tried to access repos using chrome and tortoisvn, http and https, turning off my clash proxy, but they all gave HTTP ERROR 502.
In the past I used Visual SVN server on my Windows workstation, and my laptop can checkout repos if connected to university network. Now I can't figure out what's going wrong when my workstation changes system to Ubuntu. Thanks in advance!
Here is my configurations:

my repository directory: /repos/svn/MATLAB
my apache-svn configuration: /etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf

  <Location /svn>
     DAV svn
     SVNParentPath /repos/svn
     SVNListParentPath On
     AuthType Basic
     AuthName "Subversion Repository"
     AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
     Require valid-user
  </Location>


my apache port configuration: /etc/apache2/ports.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
        NameVirtualHost *:443
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        NameVirtualHost *:443
        Listen 443
</IfModule>



my repos url format: https://<hostname>/svn/MATLAB, and I get my host name from ifconfig | grep inet, which prints

inet <hostname> netmask <...> broadcast <...>


Well, this blog How to Setup Apache Subversion with Let's encrypt SSL on Ubuntu 18.04 enlightened me. I didn't allow my firewall for http and https, which might be the reason my laptop has been blocked away from svn server. After setting:
ufw allow http
ufw allow http

and reload ufw (if have enabled already)
ufw reload

Now my laptop can checkout the repos!
Thanks for everyone who has tried to solve this problem for me!
